# getting unexpected output for entered number to find the cube

Tags: c

HERE I am not just trying to find out only cube of any number but i want to find out the entered number is to multiply by the count of its digit.
ex:- 100 to multiply by 100 three times.

Whenever i am entering a number of more then of 3 digits i am getting 
unexpected output in negative number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int cube(int);

void main()
{
    int n,ans;

    printf("enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d" , &n);

   ans=cube(n);
    printf("%d" , ans);
}

int cube(int num)
{
    int count,temp,i,add=1;

    temp=num;
    while(temp>0)
    {
        temp=temp/10;
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n" , count);

    for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
        add=add*num;
    }

    return add;
}
```

Ex:-

enter a number : 1000
4
-727379968

But at the same time when i am entering the number as 10101

enter a number : 10101
5
1343051877

i am getting this output.

Comment: Pro tip: When you get nonsense values like this it's almost always a case of *uninitialized variables*. What is `count` set to before incrementing? Answer: Nothing in particular. Since the compiler doesn't think you care, it just uses *whatever* as a value. Compile with `-Wall` to expose problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an overflow, since 1000^4 is 1000000000000 which is certainly above the value of `INT_MAX` (2147483647 on my system). You should use an appropriate data type like `long` or check for an overflow like this:

```c
#include<limits.h>


int cube(int num)
{
    int count,temp,i,add=1;

    temp=num;
    while(temp>0)
    {
        temp=temp/10;
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n" , count);

    for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
        if (INT_MAX/num < add) {
            printf("overflow\n");
        }
        add=add*num;
    }

    return add;
}
```